# How to sign and encrypt SOAP element with Node js SOAP module

Tags: node.js, soap

I have a soap web service which required some request envelope elements to be signed and encrypt. I tried to write soap client using node js, soap module but I could not found how to do the signing part and encryption part. Can someone help me with this or suggest an alternative node module for doing the job.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the soap-x509 module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap-x509